# If there's an error, user will not proceed to checkout opencart

Tags: view, controller, opencart, checkout

Where can I find the code that prohibits checkout if there's still an error? For example in minimum quantity. If you do not meet the requirements, cart doesn't permit to checkout.

I've already started mine. The error show but permits checkout. I followed how minimum quantity works but mine's still not working. Hope you can help me.

[Custom Error Shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioGPw.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be found or added in to `catalog > controller > checkout > cart`. If you cannot find it there, you will have to add it in.